# Jquery Masonry with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jquery-masonry, angularjs-directive

in my project i try to implement jquery masonry. but its getting working. i try googling but found some post. but i tried it its not working.

my directive code is

```
shout.directive("shoutList", function($timeout) {
    return  {
        restrict : 'E',

        replace : true,

        templateUrl : 'views/shout/shout-list.html',

        scope : {
            shouts : "="
        },

        //require : "ShoutController",

        controller : function($scope)   {
            $scope.deleteShout = function() {
                console.log('shout deleted');
            }
        },

        link : function(scope, element, attr)   {
            scope.$watch('shouts', function()   {
                // console.log("changing......");
                // scope.$evalAsync(
                    document.getElementById("shout-content-holder").masonry({
                        itemSelector: '.shout'
                    })
                // );
            });
        }
    }
});
```

directive template is

```
<div id="shout-content-holder">
    <div class="shout" ng-repeat="shout in shouts">
        <p>{{shout.message}}</p>
        <img src="media/images/delete.png" width="32" height="32" ng-click="deleteShout()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

i load the shouts from a webservice. please help me to make this work...

Comment: You can always try writing your own masonry kind of directive like: http://plnkr.co/edit/UyRS0clrCwDpSrYgBsXS?p=preview

Comment: @EliteOctagon Nice snippet. Thanks you.

Comment: no problem, glad that it's useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting what I mentioned in comment as an answer. This could actually be done using a template rather than using .append() , it would be cleaner. What you'd need is a template to contain a list of columns and ng-repeat, should work just as well, but you'd have to wait for the first item to get inserted before you calculate where to insert the second item; hence the use of .append() here.

```
.directive('columns', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        itemList: '=', // a list of items
        colCount: "@"  // number of columns
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      //console.log(scope.itemList);
      var numCols = parseInt(scope.colCount);
      var colsArr = [];
      for(var i=0; i< numCols; i++){
        colsArr.push(angular.element("<div class='column' style='width:"+(100/numCols -.5)+"%' >Col "+(i+1)+"</div>"));
         elm.append(colsArr[i]); 
      }

      angular.forEach(scope.itemList, function(value, key){
        var item = angular.element("<div class='item' style='height:"+value.height+"px; background:"+'#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)+"'>"+value.value+"</div>");
        var smallestColumn = getSmallestColumn();
        angular.element(smallestColumn).append(item);
      });

      function getSmallestColumn(){
        var smallestHeight = colsArr[0][0].offsetHeight;
        var smallestColumn = colsArr[0][0]; 
        angular.forEach(colsArr, function(column, key){ 
          if(column[0].offsetHeight < smallestHeight){
            smallestHeight = column[0].offsetHeight;
            smallestColumn = colsArr[key]; 
          }
        }); 
        return smallestColumn;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

plnkr.co/edit/UyRS0clrCwDpSrYgBsXS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to trigger your masonry() call on the $last ng-repeat instead of using $watch.  I just recently answered a question about this, so I will refer you there:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14656888/215945

Comment: @Jaison, can you provide a [fiddle](http://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/using-jsfiddle-with-angularjs/) or [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/) of your code?  You can use $timeout instead of $http to simulate getting data from the server.