# Directive after ngRepeat update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having some AngularJS trouble with firing off a directive when ng-repeat has completed an update.  I have three named arrays, switched to via three links, allowing the selected array to be displayed by the ng-repeat.  I'd like to fire some code off when it's finished as I'm planning to set some element attributes for D3 to use.

I've tried checking scope.$last in my directive, but this isn't called at the end of every ng-repeat process.  If some of the data remains the same, it may not set scope.$last to true.

http://plnkr.co/edit/hwmOlI6YrgS4H1C1h7k2?p=preview

So, what's the best way to trigger code in a directive when ng-repeat has finished?

Comment: Where does this directive go?  Can you update the plunk with the directive? I know it needs to go inside the ng-repeat. If you could update the plunk with the directive it would make it easier to solve your problem.

Comment: Updated the plunk with a more obvious name, it was in there as the attribute testing="" on the li element.  Renamed it to testdirective so it stands out more.

Comment: Sorry, dint see that , my bad :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution for you. Note that the last triggers each time now.

http://plnkr.co/edit/xV1quqzorzxliS2shrP4?p=preview

You just need to `$watch` the $`last` variable and it will work fine. This helps in situations where the `scope` is not created but just updated with new values. Your directive gets created once and if one of the repeated variable just changes values `ng-repeat` optimizes and just updates values ( as opposed to removing all the values and re-creating the new ones. ). In this scenario, the `$scope.$last` will be an updated variable and not something that gets "created". So, you will need to `$watch` it.

Comment: That worked, thanks :) My only issue left is that sometimes d3 is grabbing a data attribute and it still has {{data.changerate}} instead of the value (e.g. 20).  Most of the time though it's been parsed and the value is returned.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I am not exactly sure where and in what scenario you are attempting to do this, but if you are doing <div data-someattrib="{{data.changerate}}"></div>

Then you can get the value of that attribute by doing attrs.$observe(data-someattrib,function(newValue){

});

Comment: Something like that.  Check out http://plnkr.co/edit/aSXs6mGgQmvpGCL1i1IZ I've console.log'ed the data D3 ends up returning.  If you switch from page "one" to "two" you'll see {{reference[id].count}} in the array from some entries.  Not sure how to combine observe with d3.

Comment: Could you let me know what you are trying to achieve? It somehow seems like what we are doing here is a myopic view and a complete picture would provide for a better solution.

Comment: @MisterDai, you may need to use `$timeout` in your $watch callback. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14656888/215945 for a very similar issue.

Comment: @MarkRajcok awesome :) Looks like using $timeout did the trick.  Now switching between the different tables (rows built with ngRepeat) allows my D3 directive to fire, check the data and colour the cells. http://github.yougeezer.co.uk/alpha/#/repositories