# Using ng-repeat in other directive with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Firstly I'm really sorry if the following questions sound stupid. I know there are documentations but there is not enough example and I'm quite new with it.

I tried to create a directive that might make use of `ng-repeat` 
However it seems like that when the directive is linked, `ng-repeat` hasn't been evaluated at all. So whenever I tried to call the jQuery function inside the `postlink` function, the jQuery wouldn't work.

```
<div my-directive>
  <div ng-repeat="image in images">
    <img ng-src="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

The scope contains something like this:

```
scope.images = ['http://placehold.it/100x100', 'http://placehold.it/100x100'];
```

In the directive I had roughly like the following:

```
angular.module('mymodule', []).directive('myDirective', function factory() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      // #1
      return {
        pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, transclude) {
          // #2
        },
        post: function postLink (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
          // #3
        }
      };
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      // jQuery code to convert the element
      // #4
    }
  };
});
```

In addition, what's the difference between putting the code on #1, #2, #3 and #4 above? What's the rule of thumb here?
Where to put a code like probably jQueryUI's `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();`? Since from what I understand there, the function will manipulate (transform) the element and its children.
Thanks.

Comment: you should be putting all event handlers and custom registrations inside the link function so you should be putting the datepicker code inside the link function

Comment: `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker()` should be in the link/post function

Comment: both compile and link will not work, its either compile or link

Comment: if you remove `my-directive` does `ng-repeast` work

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yeah, with and without `my-directive` `ng-repeat` works. The thing is when `postLink` gets called, I don't think `ng-repeat` is evaluated yet. So when the `jQuery` code is executed in `postLink`, the code does not take effect and the result on the page is only repeated `<div><img></div>`

Answer (score 4):

The main difference between the places (explained [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), at **Compile function** and **Linking function** chapters), is that the `#1` is the **`compile function`**. Here you should practice any DOM transformations that, in case of cloning, should be cloned to all elements. This does not apply to Datepicker, as it not only modifies the DOM, but also need to listen events from it. If you add a children element that have a directive, or if you add a directive to a children element, it still gets compiled if you do it here.

The `#2` is the **`preLinking function`** and will be called after the compilation, but before children linking function. This means that you can't change the DOM, because the next linker iteration will try to find the elements previously index by compilation function and will fail. `#3` is the **`postLinking function`** and is called after all children were linked, and it's the safest place to apply singular modifications, listen to events and do any neat stuff.

You could also return a `function` instead of a `{pre: , post: }` object. In this case, it have the same behavior as `#3` (`postLinking function`). At last, `#4` is the same as `#3`. It's ignored when you have `#3`.

In case of multiple directives, in the element itself or its children, all **`compile function`** will run, than all **`preLinking functions`**, then all **`postLinking functions`**

Now, to the **main question**: `#3`, if you need a compile function. If not, just drop the `compile` property and goes for `#4`.

Made a [fiddle to illustrate](http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/zEuCu/) these behaviors.

**About the image not loading**, you should change `<img ng-src="image">` to `<img ng-src="{{image}}">` as you need Angular to interpolate the `src` property.

Comment: That cleared it up more. Thanks. So I was correct putting the `jQuery` code there. However do you know why was the `ng-repeat` not compiled correctly?

Comment: Sorry @verdy, forgot this one. There it goes. Updated the answer.

Comment: Well, actually that's what I was going with (I didn't copy paste my code as it was). To be more in detail, you can refer to my comment in response to ArunPJohny's comment (I think because `ng-repeat` has not been evaluated when the `jQuery` code in `postLink` is executed).

Comment: Seems you need to give a break to the ng-repeat/HTML-render. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15179624/179138). This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/c6Mze/) shows the use of `$timeout`. But [this second one](http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/c6Mze/5/) is a better solution, if you don't necessarily need a parent directive. This second is more indicated as it builds a reusable Datepicker directive.