# Trying to make my AngularJS directive wait for interpolation to happen

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to setup a directive to wrap the bootstrap popover component. My problem is to make the link function to wait for my details list to be interpolated.

To do so this is my HTML:

```
<div class="popover fade top in">
    Blah blah
    <br />
    <span ng-repeat="detail in details" >
        {{ detail.title }}
    </span>
</div>

<div my-popover>
    My text line that opens the popover on mouseover.
</div>
```

And my directive :

```
portalModule.directive('myPopover', function ($compile, $interpolate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace : false,
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            var updateLater = function () {
                var popoverHtml = $(element).siblings('.popover').html();

                var options = {
                    html: true,
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    content: popoverHtml
                };

                $(element).popover(options);
            }

            setTimeout(updateLater, 2000);
        }
    }
});
```

This is for now the best (only) way I found to make it work. 
- I tried using a $watch but could'nt find how to make it wait for the whole 'details' list to be interpolated.
- Angular.UI does not seem to manage rich (html) popovers yet.

Any idea/lead on how to manage that ?

[EDIT] Here is a plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/Rn2SBaiGNz4mj0F80IT3) of my issue with : 
- A new solution (to deffer the popover creation on user mouseover)
- A post link that stays KO

Comment: See if this helps any: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15179624/215945

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I played a bit more with that, using the postLink but still KO. I'm editing my question to add a plunker

Answer (score 1):

I like your new solution better than what I'm going to present... but another way to get it to work is to add a directive  (`eventOnLast`) to your ng-repeat that will check for `$last`, and then send an event that a `myPopoverLink` directive can listen for:

```
<li ng-repeat="detail in details" event-on-last>
```

```
myModule.directive('eventOnLast', function($rootScope) {
  return function(scope, element) {
    if(scope.$last === true) {
      element.ready(function () {
        console.log('broadcast');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('event:interpolationDone');
      })
    }
  }
})
myModule.directive('myPopoverLink', function ($compile, $interpolate) {
    return function (scope, element) {
      scope.$on('event:interpolationDone', function() {
        console.log('event');
        doPopover(element);
      })
    }
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GGKSd5n9GmS0Zq8Gby1W?p=preview)

`element.ready()` is needed so that `{{ detail.title }}` will get interpolated.

Also, in your plunker, I noticed you included Angular before jQuery.  If you want Angular to use jQuery (rather than its built-in jqLite), jQuery must be included first.

Comment: Here you means that the `element.ready()` method will fired *after* the interpolation is done? I've read the source code of `element.ready` and found it's not behave like what you said...

Answer (score 1):

I just came across a similar situation. I used a similar solution to yours, but just used the $timeout service. I believe the code inside the function that is passed as parameter will run after the next digest so you don't need to wait 2 seconds.

```
  $timeout(function() {
..this will run after interpolation
}
```

Here is you code using this technique

```
portalModule.directive('myPopover', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace : false,
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            $timeout(function () {

                var popoverHtml = $(element).siblings('.popover').html();

                var options = {
                    html: true,
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    content: popoverHtml
                };

                $(element).popover(options);
            });
        }
    }
});
```