# angularjs, ng-repeat and DOM elements size

Tags: javascript, dom, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a part of code, like this:

```
<div class="wrapper-directive">
   <div class="table" style="display:table">
      <div class="column" style="display:table-cell;" ng-repeat="column in columns">   
        {{column.text}}</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

How can I get width of repeated "column" elements from "wrapperDirective"? 
As I understood, I need something like onDomRepeatComplete event, but at this moment I still can't find correct solution and syntax and using just setTimeout pause ...

Answer (score 1):

`$last` can be used to determine when the last <div> is being created. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roychoo/XVzUW/3/) (I didn't write it) for an implementation of a `checkLast` directive that you can attach to your <div> element:

```
directive('checkLast', function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
     if (scope.$last === true) {
        element.ready(function () {
           // determine width here using jQuery or JavaScript
           // If that doesn't work try with $timeout:
           // $timeout(function() { 
           //    ...
           //}, 0, false);  // remove false if you need $apply to run
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/13906907/215945